Attempting to build a Multi-fact Relationship model in Tableau - I don't seem to be given the option to add a second base table?
I am in a fresh Tableau workbook, Professional Edition v.2024.1.3 connected to a MS SQL Server database
I have two fact tables that are unrelated to each other, but share several dimension tables.
I am trying to build a multi-fact relationship model with both of them to be efficient with extracts and storage.
According to the main Tableau site, this is as easy as dragging a second fact table into a zone designated for "New Base Table"
https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/datasource_mfr_build.htm#build-the-model
how it should work.png
unfortunately, when I've added my first fact table, there is no "New Base Table" area for me to utilize. Instead, as I attempt to drag another fact table underneath my first, it insists on forcing a relationship between them that I'm not able to break.
no-New-Base-Table.png
forced relationship.png
I have tried doing this in the physical layer instead, but this just causes it to attempt a join instead.
Has anyone successfully used a multi-fact model that can help me out?
I attempted to add the dimension tables first, and then add in the second fact table, but that doesn't create independent relationships - rather the second fact table is joined into the first through the dims.
In fact, on the logical layer, I was not even able to create more than one relationship to the second fact table - dragging it onto a new dimension table simply swapped the relationship to that table.
Trying things in the physical layer were not any better. I could make multiple join conditions but they were still joined, and these fact tables are meant to be separate and independent.

The next version of Tableau due to be released very soon, version 2024.2, is scheduled to allow multiple base tables.

@AlexBlakemore so the article that Tableau wrote isn't even for a feature that currently exists, is that it?

The article you cited mentions version 2024.2 which is due to release shortly I’ve heard. There may have been some support for multiple base tables in early versions (I’m not sure) but at TC24 they showed a big upgrade in that area coming in version 2024.2

Tableau 2024.2 released July 1 with support for multiple fact tables (actually multiple root tables) https://www.tableau.com/products/new-features —
